# Implementing collect.js code on two different commerce sites to collect abandoned cart data into 1 business unit with 2 brands

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, behavioral-triggers

We have 2 separate retail brands set up in 1 SFMC business unit through which we send all journeys. Now we are implementing abandoned cart journey for these 2 brands using journey builder behavioral triggers. Since these are separate brands, we are implementing collect.js code on these two commerce sites.

The question is can SFMC collect abandoned cart information from 2 sites into 1 Business unit? If Yes, how should I upload 2 separate product catalogs to support these journeys?

Comment: You can only import one catalog, so you would need to either combine them, or use different BU, depending on if you plan on using recommendations also